# перегрузить оператор>> для ifstream так чтоб он выводил данные из файла в конструктор

Tags: c++, классы, методы, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

я не пойму что добавить в аргументы, конструктор в методе вызвать или возвращать как то конструктор. в общем суть в том что я сохранил продукт а (белок,углеводы,жир) и вывод из файла должен создавать обьект продукт а с такими же данными.
я начал делать вот так: но понимаю что какой то бред

```
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& fin, product p1 ) 
{
    fin >> p1.Name;
    fin >> p1.Belok;
    fin >> p1.Gur; 
    fin >> p1.Yglevod;
    (fin >> p1.Kkal).get();
    return fin;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, для начала нужно передавать `p1` по ссылке. Во-вторых, у вас два варианта:
i) вы можете использовать такой оператор, как написали, передавая ему, например, объект `product`, созданный по умолчанию:

```
product p;
fin >> p;
```

ii) вы можете создать конструктор с параметром-потоком.

```
product::product(istream&) { ... }
...
product p(fin);
```

Делайте то, что вас больше устроит :)

Comment: спасибо, вроде бы второй вариант попроще будет

Comment: Рад помочь :) Если ответ устраивает - помечайте как принятый...